# Angular routing with extras

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, optional-parameters

I have a small website which I want to make with Angular. The site consists 3 type of contents:
- a list, which is actually the index, the '/'
- a unique written content, which is the '/r'
- a suv view for the elements from the list
I have all three type of views, but with the routing i am in problem.
I have already a controller which handles the work object, and create the list from it (arrayed key-value pairs in an array, title, subtitle, thumbnail image, etc for each work item), but when I click on one of the list items, the subpage of it should appear. I want to use it with the default $index attribute, which is enough for me now. But can I use the controller which I made for the listing or should I make another one?
for helping, this is my app.js:

```
    (function(){
    var app = angular.module("portApp", ["ngRoute"]);
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        .when("/", { // default, basically the list-view
            controller: "",
            templateUrl: "/listView.html"
        });
        .when("/r", { // about section-s content
            controller: "",
            templateUrl: "/resumeView.html"
        });
        .when("/w/:wId", { // sub pages from the list view - $index
            controller: "???",
            templateUrl: "/itemView.html"
        });
        .otherwise({ // otherwise redirect to the listView
            redirectTo: "/"
        });
    });
    app.controller("PortController", function(){ // controller for the listView
        this.products = work;
    });
    var work = [
        {
            Title: "Carlsberg / Dreher",
            subTitle: "Sörösdoboz tervek ",
            Link: "sorok",
            Thumbnail: "img/portfolio08.png",
            Image: "img/sorokmont.png"
        },
        {
            Title: "Pepsi",
            subTitle: "Kristályvíz Promóció",
            Link: "pepsi",
            Thumbnail: "img/portfolio13.png",
            Image: "img/pepsimont.png"
        }    
    ]
})();
```

How should I finish this?

OR should I use somehow the item's Link attribute from listView and send it over to the itemView with the controller?

Comment: you can use $location.path in controller.

Comment: I would store 'work' in a factory service and call that from the controller instead of making it a global variable. Then before the route change you should call a 'setProduct()' method from within the factory service. Make a new controller for the product page that checks the factory service for the set product and loads that into the scope. Or use $routeParams and load the entire 'work' array and use $routeParams.wId to access the index of the product you want.

Comment: Thank you @Rorschach120, but I am newbie to Angular, so just trying to make things work, right now:$ So i changed a little my code, there is now locationProvider too in my js file and I made up 2 controllers: 1 to define my work array which I iterate through (this is for the list view), and 1 new to handle the details. I changed the work.Link value -removed the .html from it-, and want to pass it through to the other controller and get the relevant datas only. But how should I made it with service?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer since I won't have room here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a factory with your 'work' array you would do something like this:

```
app.factory('workFactory', function() {
  var scope = this;

  scope.work = [
        {
            Title: "Carlsberg / Dreher",
            subTitle: "Sörösdoboz tervek ",
            Link: "sorok",
            Thumbnail: "img/portfolio08.png",
            Image: "img/sorokmont.png"
        },
        {
            Title: "Pepsi",
            subTitle: "Kristályvíz Promóció",
            Link: "pepsi",
            Thumbnail: "img/portfolio13.png",
            Image: "img/pepsimont.png"
        }    
    ];

  return scope;
}
```

And then in your controller you would inject it and call it

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, workFactory, $routeParams) {
  $scope.work = workFactory.work;
  $scope.product = scope.work[$routeParams.wId];
});
```

Factories are the same across your app so when you set a factory attribute in one controller it remains true for another. This is different from other service types that only provide an instance of themselves.

Comment: Ahh thank you. Only one question which is unclear to me right now.. til this I had only a simple array, which was called in the controller with the this.product = work row. But now if I put the scope into a factory, how can i acces it for the other controller?         portApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
        this.products = $scope.work;
    });

Comment: I'm just using the word scope in the factory. it could be `var banana = this; return banana;` It is just being used to return the contents of the factory. Just inject the factory into the controller the same way I did above.